# Specifying Argument Type For List of Dictionary For a Python Function

Tags: python, dictionary, types, arguments

I have a function whose argument is a list of dictionaries. I am trying to specify the type of elements for the dictionary in the function argument. The dictionary has the following form:

```
{'my_object':my_object, 'data':int}
```

`my_object` is a custom datatype. Is there any way to specify the type of dictionary, something like the one in below:

```
def my_function(x : list[dict[my_object, int]]):
```

Python complains about how I defined the type and gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: [`typing.TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) might be what you're looking for?

Comment: The `TypeError` message is true: the `list` and `dict` classes is not subscriptable.You need to use `List` and `Dict`, after importing them from `typing`. However, neither is quite what you want; as @IainShelvington points out, you probably want `typing.TypedDict` (new in Python 3.8). I don't think you can state the type of your parameter `x` as accurately as you'd like in Py3.7 -- no type for dicts with heterogeneous values (or keys).

Comment: @AFPP Did you ever get a good resolution on this?

Comment: Your use of `dict` *assumes* that all the keys are strings, and you are simply listing the *value* types, but you aren't indicating which key maps to which types. Positional order isn't appropriate: would your use case  really consider `{'data': int, "my_object": my_object}` to have a different, incorrect type?

Answer (score 22):

You can try this:

```
from typing import List, Dict


def get_list_of_dicts(name: str, surname: str) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    return [{'name': name, 'surname': surname}]


print(get_list_of_dicts('Frank', 'Zappa'))
```

I hope it is useful for you.

Answer (score -1):

If  you are asking can you specify a list of dictionaries containing a custom object as keys, then the answer is below.  If you wish to specify more than one type of object as a key within the same dictionary though, this won't work.

You can do the former in Python 3.9 with type aliases.  Reference https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html gives example with list of dicts.

Example below shows a list of dicts containing custom objects as keys.

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

class MyClass: 
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.attr1 = arg1 + arg2

class AnotherClass: 
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.attr1 = arg1 + arg2
    
seq1 = dict[MyClass, int]
seq2 = list[seq1]

def myfunc(arg1: Sequence[seq2]) -> seq2:
    for dict in arg1:
        for key, value in dict.items():
                print(key.attr1, value)

#Correct type provided.
myobj1 = MyClass('A', '1')
myobj2 = MyClass('B','2')
listdict= [{myobj1: 10, myobj2: 20}, {myobj2: 100, myobj1: 200}]
listdict
myfunc(listdict)

#Incorrect type provided.  
myobj1 = AnotherClass('A', '1')
myobj2 = AnotherClass('B','2')
listdict= [{myobj1: 10, myobj2: 20}, { myobj2: 100, myobj1: 200}]
myfunc(listdict)
        

A1 10
B2 20
B2 100
A1 200
```

Note: Linters may not recognize valid inputs though.  E.g. mypy complains that the list of dict(object, int) is not a sequence thereof.

Comment: This assumes that the keys of `dict` are all of type `MyClass`; the example in the question talks about a `dict` with string keys, but each key's *value* has a particular type.

Comment: @Chepner, thank you for noticing that.  Corrected as above.

Comment: You didn't really fix anything. You are just pointing out that the OP's attempt is no longer a type error. It still doesn't do what the OP is actually asking about, even in Python 3.9.

Comment: OP: 'my_object is a custom datatype. Is there any way to specify the type of dictionary, something like the one in below:' The issue is that he specifies it and gets a 'subscriptable' error. My answer shows that yes there is a way to specify it without getting the subscriptable error.

Comment: "The dictionary has the following form: {'my_object':my_object, 'data':int}
". Their attempt is wrong whether or not `dict` supports index notation.

Comment: I see your point that the OP in the first few lines seems to ask for a dictionary where specific keys of different types are specified.  However further down they ask for something of the form  def my_function(x : list[dict[my_object, int]]): To me [my_object, int] refers to keys equalling my_object and values being int. In which case the answer stands.

Comment: That's what they *tried*, which is still wrong. You aren't answering the question they actually asked.